# Validation an integer input from a form

Tags: validation, symfony

I have an entity with several fields in it. One of them is being validated after form submission as follows:

```
/**
 * @var integer $anzahl
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="anzahl", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Bitte geben Sie eine Kistenanzahl an.")
 * @Assert\Type(type="numeric", message="Die Kistenanzahl muss eine Zahl sein.")
 * @Assert\Min(limit="1", message="Sie müssen mindestens eine Kiste suchen oder anbieten.")
 */
private $anzahl;
```

I am having two problems with this solution:

Only integer values higher than zero should be accepted. However also floats/doubles are being accepted by this validation. However, if I change `@Assert\Type(type="numeric")` to `@Assert\Type(type="integer")` no input is validated as true. How can I validate my input to be an integer value?

The other problem is, after entering an obviously invalid value (like a string of letters) I receive not only my German error message for Type validation but also the English message 'This value should be a valid number'. Where does this message come from and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: English message 'This value should be a valid number' comes from IntegerType (and maybe other Types) and can be overriden with ['invalid_message' => 'String in German']

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use:

```
@Assert\Type(type="integer")
```

But be careful, you should use it with an `IntegerType`, not a `NumberType` or a `TextType`:

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType
```

`IntegerType` is identical to `NumberType` except that it integrates the proper [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

Comment: `@Assert\Type(type="integer")` is not working. That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Have you seen second part of answer? What form type are you using for this property?

Comment: Assert\Min() is deprecated

http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/Min.html

Comment: This answer has been posted 2 years ago.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
 ->add('field_name', 'integer', array(
     'label' => 'Your label here', 
     'data' => 0, // default value
     'precision' => 0, // disallow floats
     'constraints' => array(
         new Assert\NotBlank(), 
         new Assert\Type('integer'), 
         new Assert\Regex(array(
             'pattern' => '/^[0-9]\d*$/',
             'message' => 'Please use only positive numbers.'
             )
         ),
         new Assert\Length(array('max' => 2))
     )
 ))
```

Comment: Hello Tony
In my case regex is working very well but  Type function integer is not working. This is wondering for me because i have checked all the code i have already added use Type in my code.

Answer (score 11):

If the field type should be a string, you can use this instead:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="digit")
 */
```

Although it is not mentioned [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html), `TypeValidator` also utilizes `ctype_*` functions.

See [`\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\TypeValidator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/TypeValidator.php#L36):

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
  ...

  $ctypeFunction = 'ctype_'.$type;

  ...

  } elseif (function_exists($ctypeFunction) && call_user_func($ctypeFunction, $value)) {

  ...
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I've created a pull request to add this to the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/\d+/")
 */
```

or create a validator with `ctype_digit`.

Comment: As this is a solution that accepts numbers even using `text` as the field type, it has the downside that it accepts values like "**123ABC**". Maybe this pattern would be more useful, as it also does not accept values starting with leading zeros: `* @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^([1-9][0-9]*)$/")`

Comment: Shorter version does not start with 0, then only digits are accepted`@Assert\Regex(pattern="/^(?!0)\d+$/")`

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Symfony v2.3 version you should use:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
 * @Assert\GreaterThan(0)
 */
```

But keep in mind that forms field type should be integer (`IntegerType::class`), otherwise i'll get negative validation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `number` in form field type, but it showed an asterisk `*` next to the input label although it is not mandatory. So,I had to use `'required' => false` as well. The form field type `integer` did not work. The underlying field data type is `smallint`.

```
->add('storey', 'number', array('required' => false))
```

The `Regex` constraint in YML is not working too while type is `integer` or nothing provided. I don't know why

```
storey:
    - Regex: '/^[0-9]+$/'
```

My Symfony version is 2.7.

Comment: In my case regex is working very well but  Type function integer is not working. This is wondering for me because i have checked all the code i have already added use Type in my code.